# Can`t deploy Java restful WS using Maven, TomEE and Jersey

Tags: java, apache, web-services, maven, jersey

Нello! I'm trying to create an elementary rest-application using Java, Maven and Jersey server on Apache-tomee server 1.7.3.

org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:162)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:91)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)...

simple class

```
 package restClasses;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

/**
 * Created by Gorbenko.Oleksii on 1/19/2016.
 */

@Path("/converter")
public class Calculation {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response someAction() {

        return Response.status(200).build();
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml`enter code here` version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.gorbenko</groupId>
    <artifactId>gorbenko</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>calc</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>ru.example.rest.resource</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/restApplication/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

please, help

Comment: You are missing the full exception message

Comment: Jan 24, 2016 8:38:29 AM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor processRequest
WARNING: No root resource matching request path /calc/restApplication/converter/c has been found, Relative Path: /calc/restApplication/converter/c. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.
Jan 24, 2016 8:38:29 AM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNING: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:162)

Comment: Tomee comes with CXF as it JAX-RS implementation bundled. Your Jersey dependencies and web.xml are generally not necessary, so delete them to avoid confusion. See the examples [here](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-rest/README.html)

Comment: it didn't work anyway
even when i create default restful project with hello world by IDEA - it doesn't works...

I despair...
tomcat works fine...
in what can be problem?

Comment: forgot

thnks a lot for answer )